# How to permanently change the time in Ubuntu Server

Tags: 11.04, server, time

I have changed the time in Ubuntu Server 11.04 but when i reboot it resets to the default it has. How to change the time that when I boot it stays like i changed it. already tried `date` but I think this is only temporary.

Comment: Well when I type date I wanted to show the time I have in my country. But the timezone thing I did not think about it.

Comment: date is permanent if you are not using a timeserver and the correct timezone ;)

Comment: @Marco - Thank you the problem was in the timezone. I did 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata', selected the correct place and done. Works perfect after reboot. If you can put it as an answer i will voted up.

Comment: Answer added!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like you have a timezone issue. The easiest way to fix this is to reconfigure the `tzdata` package `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

There are alternative ways, like symlinking the correct zonefile from `/usr/share/zoneinfo` to `/etc/localtime` which will inform the system of the proper time:

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
```

However, it's preferred to use `dpkg-reconfigure`

Answer (score 3):

If your timezone is set up correctly, I think you have to adjust your hardware clock with the command `hwclock`.